Is my power supply well scaled?
EDIT
Sorry that I have bother you ... I found my mistake thank to your idea @Attie it was reversed polarity ... I plugged this jack female whe I wasn't awake enough !
One picture is worth a thousand words :'|

I'm using a 12V 6A power supply to power an arduino + 6 pumps (DC motors basically) + an HC-05 BLE module.
In order to power up the ardunio which controls the 6 pumps with 6 MOSFETs IRL540N I'm using this kind of LM2596 step down module :

But it exploded when I plugged the power supply :

Here is how I have plugged everything :

I'm wondering if something's wrong in my solderings / wires or in the sketch / idea itself ?
Should I use an alimentation < 3A ? Because I read that the LM2596S could only takes 3A ... But it exploded as soon as I plugged the whole thing and not after the activation of any pump which would have "ask" for some voltage right ?

Please draw a proper schematic and provide a schematic for the LM2596 module.

Have you got a multimeter so that you can check for short-circuits before applying power?

What power supply did you use and how did you hook it up?  A blurry picture of a black and yellow wire going out of the frame doesn't tell us enough. It sounds like there was either a downstream short or the converter was defective/counterfeit.

"it exploded when I plugged the power supply" ... proper job, huh. What input are you providing? I'd be surprised if a downstream short did this, but over-voltage on the input, or reversed polarity very well could have... or as this is a cheap generic board from Amazon (or similar), it could just be defective.

"alimentation" is not a word in English, at least not in the context of electrical engineering. I think it means "power supply" in French, but I'm not certain of that--could you clarify?

Sorry all, thanks @Allie it was indeed a reversed polarity ! n_n
